# Zuul Load balancer does not have available server for client

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I've been trying to connect microservices using Zuul and Eureka and have succeeded for the most part except re-routing through Zuul based on serviceId. What I have is Spring Boot Zuul and Eureka applications, and a Node-based microservice which registers with Eureka. Both Zuul and the microservice are registered with Eureka and show up on the Eureka control panel, however, when I try to route through Zuul to the microservice I get the following exception:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: steam-auth-service
```

Routing through IP seems to work, but I don't need that.

Zuul application.properties:

```
server.port=8079
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8088/eureka
zuul.routes.steam-auth-service.serviceId=steam-auth-service
zuul.routes.steam-auth-service.path=/steam/**
```

Node.JS Eureka client registration:

```
// Discovery service info
const eurekaServer = {
  host: process.env.EUREKA_HOST,
  port: process.env.EUREKA_PORT,
  servicePath: '/eureka/apps/',
};

// Client to connect to Eureka discovery service
const eurekaClient = new Eureka({
  instance: {
    app: 'steam-auth-service',
    hostName: 'localhost',
    ipAddr: '127.0.0.1',
    port: {
      $: process.env.PORT,
      '@enabled': true,
    },
    vipAddress: 'steamauth.pubgtrade.com',
    dataCenterInfo: {
      '@class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
      name: 'MyOwn',
    },
  },
  eureka: eurekaServer,
});
```

As I said, both the Zuul application and the microservices are registered with Eureka and show up in the control panel.

/eureka/apps response:

```
<applications>
<versions__delta>1</versions__delta>
<apps__hashcode>UP_2_</apps__hashcode>
<application>
<name>STEAM-AUTH-SERVICE</name>
<instance>
<hostName>localhost</hostName>
<app>STEAM-AUTH-SERVICE</app>
<ipAddr>127.0.0.1</ipAddr>
<status>UP</status>
<overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
<port enabled="true">3001</port>
<securePort enabled="false">7002</securePort>
<countryId>1</countryId>
<dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
<name>MyOwn</name>
</dataCenterInfo>
<leaseInfo>
<renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
<durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
<registrationTimestamp>1514334766260</registrationTimestamp>
<lastRenewalTimestamp>1514334886300</lastRenewalTimestamp>
<evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
<serviceUpTimestamp>1514333831189</serviceUpTimestamp>
</leaseInfo>
<metadata class="java.util.Collections$EmptyMap"/>
<vipAddress>steamauth.pubgtrade.com</vipAddress>
<isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
<lastUpdatedTimestamp>1514334766260</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
<lastDirtyTimestamp>1514334766260</lastDirtyTimestamp>
<actionType>ADDED</actionType>
</instance>
</application>
<application>
<name>PUBG-API-GATEWAY</name>
<instance>
<instanceId>192.168.0.13:pubg-api-gateway:8079</instanceId>
<hostName>192.168.0.13</hostName>
<app>PUBG-API-GATEWAY</app>
<ipAddr>192.168.0.13</ipAddr>
<status>UP</status>
<overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
<port enabled="true">8079</port>
<securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
<countryId>1</countryId>
<dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
<name>MyOwn</name>
</dataCenterInfo>
<leaseInfo>
<renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
<durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
<registrationTimestamp>1514334380413</registrationTimestamp>
<lastRenewalTimestamp>1514334890454</lastRenewalTimestamp>
<evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
<serviceUpTimestamp>1514334380413</serviceUpTimestamp>
</leaseInfo>
<metadata>
<management.port>8079</management.port>
<jmx.port>36983</jmx.port>
</metadata>
<homePageUrl>http://192.168.0.13:8079/</homePageUrl>
<statusPageUrl>http://192.168.0.13:8079/info</statusPageUrl>
<healthCheckUrl>http://192.168.0.13:8079/health</healthCheckUrl>
<vipAddress>pubg-api-gateway</vipAddress>
<secureVipAddress>pubg-api-gateway</secureVipAddress>
<isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
<lastUpdatedTimestamp>1514334380413</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
<lastDirtyTimestamp>1514334380381</lastDirtyTimestamp>
<actionType>ADDED</actionType>
</instance>
</application>
</applications>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Why not use application.yml instead of properties and this how I have it setup in mine. Are you able to get to the service directly?? i.e not via ZUUL.

```
zuul:
  routes:
     path: /steam/**
     service-id: steam-auth-service
     strip-prefix: false
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8088/eureka
```